# Difference between DexClassLoader and InMemoryDexClassLoader?

Tags: android, dynamic-class-loaders

sorry if this the wrong place to post about this, but I was wondering if anyone knows the difference between *DexClassLoader* and *InMemoryDexClassLoader*?

According to [developer.android.com](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/InMemoryDexClassLoader), *InMemoryDexClassLoader* is a ClassLoader implementation that loads classes from a buffer containing a DEX file which can be used to execute code that has not been written to the local file system.

And *DexClassLoader* is a class loader that loads classes from .jar and .apk files containing a classes.dex entry. This can be used to execute code not installed as part of an application.

I'm a bit confused on the differences between them both?

I'm planning on integrating this into an existing android app that I'm building in order to obtain a smaller APK by dynamically loading certain classes at runtime, but would like to know more about the differences between the two before I do so, so basically are there any major differences in usage between the two, will code implemented for *DexClassLoader* work with *InMemoryDexClassLoader* etc.